# UFW IP does not block nginx

Tags: nginx, iptables, firewall, ufw, alpine

I have the following problem. I have an Alpine Linux system, not in a container. An Nginx web server and the UFW firewall run on it. If an Error 400 or 404 is triggered, UFW blocks the IP. This works so far, it is in UFW (ufw status) and in iptables. I can still reach the server via Nginx. As if the Nginx server takes priority.

Here is the UFW status output:
[image]

Here ist the iptables status ouput:
[image]

Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean, I can still reach nginx? Does nginx still serve a website? I see the rules are generated by fail2ban? Is your source ip in the fail2ban list?